# Why is React.useCallback used here, instead of a normal function?

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am looking at an example in the [documentation of fluentui](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/textfield):

```
...
export const TextFieldControlledExample: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [firstTextFieldValue, setFirstTextFieldValue] = React.useState('');
  ...
  const onChangeFirstTextFieldValue = React.useCallback(
    (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>, newValue?: string) => {
      setFirstTextFieldValue(newValue || '');
    },
    [],
  );
  ...
  return (
  ...
      <TextField
        label="Basic controlled TextField"
        value={firstTextFieldValue}
        onChange={onChangeFirstTextFieldValue}
        styles={textFieldStyles}
      />
  ...
  );
};
```

Why are they using React.useCallBack here instead of a normal function? E.g. what is there to memoize?

Comment: This is useful when passing callbacks to optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent unnecessary renders. One time someone said it was kind of a best practice using this hook, but i can't confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

when you create a function at your component that function will be recreated at every rerender for that component.

When you apply [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) you memoize that function, which avoids the function being recreated at every rerender. It will only create a new function if at your dependencies array any of that dependencies values change.

It's important to note, that if you reference some state at your memoized function you may face a stale state, leading to undesired behavior. In these cases using a `setState` with a callback function would avoid that issue.